# Configuring JPA with Intellij

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jpa, intellij-idea

Im tryning to configure a JPA with intellij in a maven proyect, but when im testing the connection the connection failed :C

I tried to change localhost to 127.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0
I have the mysql dependency too

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.16</version>
    </dependency>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="PruebaPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Prueba"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The test show me:

```
Connection to Prueba@localhost failed.
[08S01] Communications link failure.
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your mysql service running you can check this in control panel. Also telnet localhost 3306. Maybe you can try bind-address entry to my.cnf

Comment: Thank you! I cheked out the services and i figure out that i didnt have mysql installed.